# Shiny renderUI only showing last output

Tags: r, dynamic, shiny

I'm trying to dynamically create some content with a for loop using `renderUI` and `uiOutput` but every rendered element only contains the information from the last iteration in the for loop. Example:

```
require(shiny)
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("out1"),
  uiOutput("out2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- 1
  for(a in c("hello", "world")){
    name <- paste0("out", count)
    output[[name]] <- renderUI({
      strong(a)
    })
    count <- count + 1
  }
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This outputs **world** twice instead of **hello** **world**

Comment: Check this: https://gist.github.com/wch/5436415/. Probably you need to add enclose the content of the for loop in `local({})`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when using `sapply` instead of a for loop:

```
require(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("out1"),
  uiOutput("out2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  vec <- c("hello", "world")

  sapply(seq_along(vec), function(x) {
    name <- paste0("out", x)
    output[[name]] <- renderUI({
      strong(vec[x])
    })
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to Alexandre's answer I figured out using `local({})` also works thanks to Zygmunt Zawadzki's comment:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput("out1"),
  uiOutput("out2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  count <- 1
  for(a in c("hello", "world")){
    local({
      b <-a #this has to be added as well
      name <- paste0("out", count)
      output[[name]] <- renderUI({
        strong(b)
      })
    })
    count <- count + 1
  }
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```